# How many permutations of the letters of the word "HIPPOPOTAMUSES" that

Tags: combinatorics

do not have the same letter at the beginning and end of the word?

I would like to use the Difference Rule:
All the permutations - permutations with the same letter at the beginning and end(P......P;O.....O;S......S)
= $\binom {14}{1,1,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,2}$-$\binom{12}{1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2}$-2$\binom{12}{1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,2}$

The correct answer I was given is 199,584,000

It seems like I forgot to minus something else, can some one help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: Why is just that 2 in the middle

Comment: @Manthanein because the number of permutation of O.....O and S....S cases are the same.

Comment: But the beginning and ending letters of the words formed overall are different making overall permutation different

Comment: @Manthanein that's why I times 2 to $\binom{12}{1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,2}$

Comment: Oh sorry I did not notice that because I work on mobile not on PC

Comment: Your answer is fine. $199\,584\,000$ is the number you are subtracting from the total.